# How to transfer an ERC721 token

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to transfer an ERC721 token, but I'm getting the error `ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved` for the `transferToken` method.

**Main.sol**

```
import "./ERC721.sol";
import "./Counters.sol";

contract Main is ERC721 {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter internal _tokenIds;
    address payable internal admin; 

    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "TOKEN") {
        admin = payable(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

**Auction.sol**

```
import "./Main.sol";

contract Auction is Main {
    struct AuctionInfo {
        uint256 tokenId;
        address highestBidder;
        uint highestBid;
    }

    mapping(string => AuctionInfo) private _auctionInfo;

    function createAuction(string memory id) public {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
        
        _auctionInfo[id].tokenId = newTokenId;
    }

    function transferToken(string memory id) public {
        require(msg.sender == _auctionInfo[id].highestBidder, "You are not the highest bidder");

        safeTransferFrom(address(this), _auctionInfo[id].highestBidder, _auctionInfo[id].tokenId);
    }

    // other methods...
}
```

The minting contract is `this` and the owner of the token is the `msg.sender` of the minting method if I'm not mistaken. Am I to use the `approve` (or `setApprovalForAll`) for `this` each time before transferring? I've tried `this`, `payable(this)`, and `address(this)` for the `safeTransferFrom` method, but none seem to be working.

For example, I tried the following, but get the same revert message:

```
 approve(address(this), _auctionInfo[id].tokenId);
 this.safeTransferFrom(address(this), _auctionInfo[id].highestBidder, _auctionInfo[id].tokenId);
```

Comment: User has to `approve` at least amount auction contract want to receive to use `transferfrom` function

Comment: @AhmadGorji could you elaborate? I updated my question to include the `approve` method I've tried.

Comment: You should approve using the tokens contract through your dapp, not through your auction contract. I guess you missed this!

Comment: @Kevvv I'm assuming the `./ERC721.sol` is a copy of the OpenZeppelin implementation. Can you specify which version and if you made any changes to it? There might be a way to perform the approval from the `Auction` contract.

Comment: @PetrHejda yes it's from OpenZeppelin Contracts v4.3.2 and I have not made any changes to it https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol

Answer (score 1):

The main principle behind any Blockchain is that nobody on the blockchain network should be trusted, and still the transactions should happen fool proof, with no possibility of any cheating being done (barring of course of some hacking).

If you invoke the approve method from the `Auction` contract, then the `msg.sender` for the approve function in the ERC721 token contract is your auction contract address. So, in other words, your Auction Contract is trying to approve itself to sell someone else's NFTs, which is not very trustworthy.

What should really happen is that owner of the NFT should invoke the `approve` method of the ERC721 contract - i.e. the transaction that you send for the `approve` function call, should be signed by the NFT owner wallet address. This way, the `msg.sender` for the `approve` function in the ERC721 contract will be the owner of the NFT. As per the ERC721 standards, the owner of the NFT can approve anyone they want, to sell their NFT(s), as the no-trust in the network is still maintained (At least I should be able to trust myself). The `approve` method should be invoked from within your DAPP, before the `transferToken` function is invoked from the DAPP.

Hope that explains why you are unable to transfer your ERC721 tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  If I'm not mistaken, the order of the events should be 1) The buyer pays for a token 2) The owner approves the operator or the buyer to transfer the token 3) The operator or the buyer transfer the token's ownership. The problem is that the seller doesn't know who is going to buy the token in advance so it doesn't make sense to have the buyer buy the token and wait fo the owner to approve that buyer, which is part of the reason why the `approve` method exist.

Comment: So how would you recommend implementing `the transaction that you send for the approve function call, should be signed by the NFT owner wallet address` at the same time the buyer invokes the `transferToken` function? Am I able to retain the seller's address somehow like this `nftContract = ERC721(msg.sender)` and invoke the transfer method from the seller's wallet `nftContract. safeTransferFrom(...parameters)`?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the `internal` visibility of the `ERC721`.`_approve()` function, you can effectively perform the approval for the user.

Then you'll be able to execute the `safeTransferFrom(tokenOwner, receiver, tokenId)` from your contract, because your contract address is approved to operate this specific token even though it belongs to the `tokenOwner`.

---

This snippet mints the token, assigning the ownership to the `msg.sender`. But then it also calls the `_approve()` function that doesn't contain any validations and simply assigns the approval of the token to the `Auction` address.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract Auction is ERC721 {
    
    constructor() ERC721("CollectionName", "Symbol") {}
    
    function createAuction() public {
        uint256 newTokenId = 1;

        _mint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
        _approve(address(this), newTokenId);
    }
    
}
```

You can see from the screenshot that the owner is `0x5B...` (the user address) and that the token is approved for `0xd9...` (the contract address).

[image: remix screenshot]

*Note: The `_approve()` function is `internal` - it can be called from the `ERC721` contract and contracts deriving from it (in your case `Main` and `Auction`), but it can't be called from external contracts or end user addresses.*

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Could you provide an example of how `safeTransferFrom` should be invoked? The method `transferToken` (which has `safeTransferFrom`) is invoked by the buyer of the token which means `msg.sender` isn't approved to transfer the token. How do I get `address(this)` to invoke `safeTransferFrom` when `transferToken` is invoked by a non-approved buyer? I've tried it with my example, but I get the same revert message. I believe the revert comes from `_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId)`.